# C++/CLI Application Crashing On Start (_register_onexit_function)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crash, c++-cli, crt

Alright, I have a C++/CLI application that works just perfectly on *debug* mode, however when I change the build to release, the program crashes before it even reaches the main() function.

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

Here are screenshots of the error:
[Program crashes on this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYDzw.png)

this is the function that the program crashes in:

```
extern "C" _onexit_t __cdecl _onexit(_onexit_t const function)
{
_PVFV* const onexit_first = __crt_fast_decode_pointer(module_local_atexit_table._first);

if (onexit_first == reinterpret_cast<_PVFV*>(-1))
{
    return _crt_atexit(reinterpret_cast<_PVFV>(function)) == 0
        ? function
        : nullptr;
}
else
{
    // here it crashes
    return _register_onexit_function(&module_local_atexit_table, function) == 0
        ? function
        : nullptr;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.  When I add a boost function, it fails at startup, before any of my code is executed.  It compiles just fine.

```
boost::archive::xml_oarchive * oa = new  boost::archive::xml_oarchive(*stream);
```

Comment: Your answer was likely downvoted because it does not appear to be related to the OP's question. Read [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](how to write a good answer) and then determine if you can edit your answer to meet those guidelines or consider deleting your answer.